Azure AI Agent Service keeps a reference to deleted connections even if not used
I do not have any agents in my Azure AI Agents service, so if I run project_client.agents.list_agents(), it correctly returns an empyt result:

{'object': 'list', 'data': [], 'first_id': None, 'last_id': None,
'has_more': False}

However, if I delete the Azure AI search connection using the following command az ml connection delete -n mmai-hub04-fvye-connection-AISearch --resource-group mmai04-rg --workspace-name mmai-hub04-prj01-fvye on this connection:

, then I cannot run the above command project_client.agents.list_agents() any more, because it complains that it can't find it any more:

DecodeError: JSON is invalid: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
Content: Exception Type: ServiceInvocationException
Message: Service invocation failed!
Request: GET account-rp.vienna-eastus.svc/rp/workspaces/subscriptions/eca2eddb-0f0c-4351-a634-52751499eeea/resourceGroups/mmai04-rg/providers/Microsoft.MachineLearningServices/workspaces/mmai-hub04-prj01-fvye/connections/mmai-hub04-fvye-connection-AISearch
Status Code: 404 NotFound
Error Code: UserError/NotFoundError
Reason Phrase: Connection mmai-hub04-fvye-connection-AISearch can't be found in this workspace
Response Body: {
"error": {
"code": "UserError",
"severity": null,
"message": "Connection mmai-hub04-fvye-connection-AISearch can't be found in this workspace",
"messageFormat": null,
"messageParameters": null,
"referenceCode": null,
"detailsUri": null,
"target": null,
"details": [],
"innerError": {
"code": "NotFoundError",
"innerError": null
},
"debugInfo": null,
"additionalInfo": null
},
"correlation": {
"operation": "00a4a960f4e36533e697a9470a71a936",
"request": "41751bf0ad5eda6a"
},
"environment": "eastus",
"location": "eastus",
"time": "2024-12-31T11:58:31.2013859+00:00",
"componentName": "account-rp",
"statusCode": 404
}

Point is, that I need to use a different connection with a different name, but even if I have a new one, any actions on agents like list_agens() or list_files() fails because it can't find the original connection name, even if it isn't used by anyone.
So my only workaround, at the moment, is to never delete the original connection.
